# Stay in directory changed after ending of bash script

Tags: bash, shell, cd

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp
```

Before running my script:

```
pwd: /
```

After running my script:

```
pwd: /
```

After runnig my script trough sourcing it:

```
pwd: /tmp
```

How I can stay at the path from the script without sourcing it ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't. Changes to the current directory only affect the current process.

Answer (score 7):

Let me elaborate a little bit on this:

When you run the script, bash creates a new process for it, and changes to the current directory only affect that process.

When you source the script, the script is executed directly by the shell you are running, without creating extra processes, so changes to the current directory are visible to your main shell process.

So, as Ignacio pointed out, this can not be done

Answer (score 5):

Ignacio is correct.  However, as a heinous hack (totally ill advised and this really should get me at least 10 down votes) you can exec a new shell when you're done

```
#!/bin/bash
...
cd /
exec bash
```

Comment: This will lead to an extra shell running (your original one). Bonus points if you can fix that, too.

Comment: I liked this one, even though you must now type exit twice to close the terminal window.  One improvement: exec bash -l (so that your command prompt is reasonable)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a silly idea.  Use PROMPT_COMMAND.  For example:

```
$ export PROMPT_COMMAND='test -f $CDFILE && cd $(cat $CDFILE) && rm $CDFILE'
$ export CDFILE=/tmp/cd.$$
```

Then, make the last line of your script be 'pwd > $CDFILE'

Answer (score 2):

If you really need this behavior, you can make your script return the directory, then use it somehow. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp
echo $(pwd)
```

and then you can

```
cd $(./script.sh)
```

Ugly, but does the trick in this simple case.

Comment: I agree - if the user REALLY needs this and cannot achieve this via a function in .bashrc function, the closest thing would be run the external script and then cd to whatever was the return HOWEVER - this implies that the external script cannot have any interaction with the user because you are consuming all of the output.  This is why William's answer seems a bit more flexible.  mayEb stderr could be used - really need more details from the user about the use case

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to run in the current shell to support this. E.g.

```
md() { mkdir -p "$1" && cd "$1"; }
```

I have the above in my ~/.bashrc

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @mob It lets users define a quick way to change to a specific/variable directory, which was likely the intent of the question and subsequent searches. +1